# Does setValueAtTime has a specific duration?

Tags: web-audio-api

In the docs says:

> The setValueAtTime() method of the AudioParam interface schedules an instant change to the AudioParam value at a precise time, as measured against AudioContext.currentTime. The new value is given in the value parameter.

From what one can think it makes an instant change but when a run this code

```
...
biquadNode.gain.setValueAtTime(12, this._AudioContext.currentTime);
console.log("biquadNode.gain " + biquadNode.gain.value);
console.log("biquadNode.frequency " + biquadNode.frequency.value);
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("biquadNode.gain " + biquadNode.gain.value);
    console.log("biquadNode.frequency " + biquadNode.frequency.value);
}, 100);
...
```

It outputs:

```
0
12
```

I am not sure why...

Answer (score 1):

It's instant, right, yet asynchronous (and is assumed to be a non-blocking op), as it's executed in a separate thread - note the word **schedules** in the description. That's why you won't see the change immediately.

Note that another method of updating `value`, via direct assignment to the corresponding property...

```
biquadNode.gain.value = 12;
```

... isn't synchronous either - and is basically equivalent to `setValueAtTime(newValue, currentTime)`, as explained [**in this issue**](https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api/issues/828).

Comment: The value setter won't be synchronous either: https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api/issues/828 (I don't think it was ever actually synchronous because the audio processing is happening on a different thread, and you can't really change the value in the middle of processing.)

Comment: @RaymondToy Thank you, that makes sense. Updated the answer with your explanation, and the documentation link.